# How to Correctly Render SVGs Exported from Figma?

Tags: reactjs, svg, figma

Background:
I am a designer venturing into the world of React, trying to integrate components designed in Figma into a React application. My strength lies in design, and I am relatively new to coding and React, so please bear with me.

Problem Description:
I am facing challenges rendering SVGs that I have exported from Figma. When I try to incorporate them into my React components, they appear distorted, and the colors are not rendering as they do in Figma.

What I have tried:
Exported SVGs from Figma:
I meticulously exported the designs as SVGs from Figma, ensuring to select the correct options.

Imported SVGs in React:
With my limited knowledge of React, I have attempted to import the SVGs and render them using both the  tag and as a background in a div.

Attempted to Adjust Styles:
I have tried to adjust the styles and attributes of the SVGs, but the distortions and color mismatches persist.

Expected Outcome:
I expected the SVGs to render accurately, reflecting the designs and colors as they are in Figma.

Actual Outcome:
The SVGs are distorted, and the colors are not accurate, which is quite frustrating as it affects the overall aesthetics of the application.

Question:
Could someone guide me on how to properly render SVGs exported from Figma in my React components, maintaining the correct proportions and colors? Are there any beginner-friendly resources or solutions that can help me integrate my designs seamlessly?

Comment: Can you share a minimal SVG that reproduces the issue when included in HTML?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.